# How to add another table to publisher and subscriber without reinitializing the subscriber?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

Is there chance to add another table in SQL Server 2005 transactional replication without reinitializing subscriber.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always 70% of answer in every question, I did research Sql Server Books Online and [found the solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> After a publication is created, it is possible to add and drop
> articles. Articles can be added at any time, but the actions required
> for dropping articles depend on the type of replication and when the
> article is dropped.
>
> Adding Articles   Adding an article involves:
> adding the article to the publication; creating a new snapshot for the
> publication; synchronizing the subscription to apply the schema and
> data for the new article